# Orient plane based on vectors

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, three.js, linear-algebra

I am want to draw a plane that has an an array of points lying on it (including the origin). The three.js library draws the plane on the origin, facing the xy plane.  Right now, I am having trouble of moving the it from the origin to a position such that it contains the points.

So far, I have managed to find a way to orient some planes that lie on the y-axis:

```
    var directionalVectors  = __getDirectionVectors(points);
    var normal = __getNormalOfPlane(directionalVectors);  
    var angleXY = __getAngleBetweenPlanes( normal, new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1) );
    plane.rotateY(- angleXY );
    plane.translateY( planeDimensions.width /2.0);
    plane.translateX( planeDimensions.height /2.0);
```

This is how I calculate the direction vectors:

```
var __getDirectionVectors = function( points ){
    var numOfPoints = points.length, i;
    var pointOne, pointTwo, directionalVectors = [], directionalVector;

    for( i = 0; i < numOfPoints - 1; i++){
        pointOne = points[i];
        pointTwo = points[i + 1];
        directionalVector = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(pointOne, pointTwo);
        directionalVectors.push(directionalVector);
    }

    return directionalVectors;
};
```

This is how I calculate the normal:

```
    var __getNormalOfPlane = function(vectors){
    var numOfVectors = vectors.length;
    var vectorOne, vectorTwo, normal;

    if( numOfVectors >= 2){
        vectorOne = vectors[0];
        vectorTwo = vectors[1];
        normal = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(vectorOne, vectorTwo);
    }
    return normal;
};
```

This is how I calculate the angle between the plane and the XY plane:

```
    //http://www.netcomuk.co.uk/~jenolive/vect14.html
    var __getAngleBetweenPlanes = function( normalOne, normalTwo){

        var dotPdt = normalOne.dot(normalTwo);
        var angle = Math.acos(  dotPdt / ( normalOne.length() * normalTwo.length() ) );
        return angle;
    }
```

Is there any way I could orient the plane properly for all types of planes?

Comment: be more specific what does angle between planes to do with this? why more planes when the title suggest you want just one ... hope origin is a point as you write only about vectors which are all relative ... What do you mean by orientation when you got the Normal vector already?

Comment: @Spektre The plane drawn by the Three.js library always draws at the origin. So I calculate the angles between the plane I want to draw and the xy-plane, xz-plane and yz plane. So that I could translate, rotate the plane drawn by Three.js into the proper position

Comment: @Spektre I only want to draw one plane each time I call the draw plane function. I just want to make sure that the function works for all types of plane. Origin is and the other vectors all are points that lie on the plane that I want to draw.

Comment: @Spektre I've got the normal vector already but I need help with moving the plane from the origin to a position where you would expect a plane with the normal vector to be. The three.js library just draws the plane at the origin, on the xy plane. Thank you for your help

Comment: Try (1) compute normal (2) `plane.lookAt( normal )` (3) `plane.position.set( newPos )`, where `newPos` is the average of your points, including the origin.

Comment: @WestLangley I have tried doing (1) (2) (3) together but i dont see anything being drawn. If I try just (1) and (2), I can see that the plane is oriented in the correct direction but the centre of the plane still at the origin. Thank you for your help

Comment: @WestLangley I was doing `plane.position.set( newPos )` where `newPos` was a `THREE.Vector3()` but after doing `plane.position.set( newPos.x, newPos.y, newPos.z )` it works. Thank so much for your help